# Change Record to Column in Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have table like below

```
CustomFieldValueId  CustomFieldId   ProjectId   CustomFieldName CustomFieldValue
35                  69              1           User Name       kaliya
36                  72              1           City            Bangalore
37                  74              1           Email           mm@gmail.com
38                  69              1           User Name       mvkperumal
39                  72              1           City            Chennai
40                  74              1           Email           mvkperumal@gmail.com
41                  69              1           User Name       Yohesh
42                  72              1           City            Delhi
43                  74              1           Email
```

I need the output like below

```
User Name   City       Email
kaliya      Bangalore  mm@gmail.com
mvkperumal  Chennai    mverumal@gmail.com
Yohesh      Delhi
```

I am taking the value based on CustomFieldValueId and grouping the ProjectId
So Please help on this..

Comment: So show us what [you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How are you connecting the values?  Why can't it be `kaliya, Chennai, ''`

Comment: I have tried i cant able to find out

Comment: I think I can see what you are trying to do, but I think your table schema is incomplete.  There is no user_id/record_id that lets us link kaliya to bangalore.  If there were, it would be possible to do this with table aliases and multiple joins.  It still wouldn't be a clever thing to do.

Comment: Can we see the query that isn't working for you please?

Comment: Why are you representing the data like this?  Why not just have a user table with username, email and city fields?  It is going to be horribly inefficient to work with this data.

Comment: @kmkperumal you are missing the point that there is nothing to link kaliya with Bangalore or mvkperumal with Chennai, other than their relative position in the table (which is not something you can count on).

Comment: You are still missing the point.

Comment: @kmkperumal you need to add a recordId column to link all the related rows together. Once in place, you can simply do a pivot to convert to the format you requested.

Comment: @davids yes, but he *shouldn't*.  This is a really stupid way to organise data in a relational database.  There might be a good reason but I doubt it.

Comment: @itsbruce I have had to do this for user defined fields.  I am guessing that is the point of the CustomFieldNamd and CustomFieldValue.  With this layout he can simply pivot for the result he expects.

Comment: @davids username is a user-defined field? I'm quite familiar with the need to deal with optional fields, but this smells bad (look at the project id in there and tell me it doesn't). Even for genuinely esoteric data, there's often a better way. But for key user data like this, likely to be searched against often and crying out to be indexed...

Comment: @itsbruce good point.  I didn't consider the data he was storing, only the structure.  Too bad we will probably never learn the justification behind why it was structured this way at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `PIVOT` but you need to have some way to associate each `User Name` with `Email`, etc.  If you can get that figured out, then you can use something like this:

```
select [User Name], [City], [email]
from
(
  select customfieldname, customfieldvalue,
    row_number() over(partition by ProjectId, CustomFieldId 
                      order by CustomFieldValueId) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
( 
  max(customfieldvalue)
  for customfieldname in ([User Name], [City], [email])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0543f/7)

Since you didn't provide a way to associate each value, I applied a `row_number()` to each record.

Comment: @kmkperumal If an answer is helpful to you be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left.  It will help future visitors and you get reputation from it.